# Rails 4 has_many issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following:

in parent.rb

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :parent_id
  has_many :scouts

  # Friendly ID
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :full_name, :use => :slugged

  # Synthesize fullname for use by FriendlyID
  def full_name
    "#{fname}-#{lname}"
  end
  def pretty_name
    "#{fname} #{lname}"
  end

end
```

in scout.rb

```
class Scout < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :scout_id, :fname, :lname
  belongs_to :parents
  has_many :insignia

  # Friendly ID
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :full_name, :use => :slugged

  # Synthesize fullname for use by FriendlyID
  def full_name
    "#{fname}-#{lname}"
  end

  def pretty_name
    "#{fname} #{lname}"
  end
end
```

I want to get the first name of the scout "owned" by a parent, so in parent_controller.rb I have:

```
  def show
    @parent = Parent.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @id = @parent.id
    @scout  = Scout.where(:scout_id => @id).all
  end
```

Since I'm storing the ID of the scout in the parent model, I've made a variable out of the id to match on. Otherwise, the id's would never match because in this case params[:id] is a friendly id slug.

Basically, how do I return single attributes on the scout model inside the parent model? For instance, I want the first name of a scout whose id matches a given parent. But when I do this in my view:

```
<p>
  <strong>Child:</strong>
  <%= @scout.fname %>
</p>
```

I get

```
undefined method `fname' for nil:NilClass
```

I realize this is pretty elementary Rails, but it's not often that I'm building multiuser systems like this. Any help or information that might shed some light on has_many relationships is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue in your controller code:

```
  def show
    @parent = Parent.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @id = @parent.id
    @scout  = Scout.where(:scout_id => @id).all
  end
```

You've found a parent object and stored into `@parent`.  You then take the ID of it, store it in `@id` but then do a lookup for all `Scout`'s who's `scout_id == @id` (which reads give me all scout's who's ID == parent_id ).  I think what you meant to do here is:

```
  def show
    @parent = Parent.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @id = @parent.id
    @scout  = Scout.where(:parent_id => @id)
  end
```

This can be refactored further though:

```
  def show
    @parent = Parent.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @scouts  = @parent.scouts
  end
```

Now `@scouts` is an array so in your view you'll want to loop through it with something like the `#each` method.

Update:

As discussed in our chat there is a bit of clean up that needs to happen first.  Remove the attr_accessor lines in both the Scout and Parent model.  Also the Scout model needs a belongs_to :parent not parents.

Comment: No luck on that. No error, but nothing returns in the view. I know there is a corresponding record, so I should get a first name back.

Comment: The each method also gets me nothing.

<% @scouts.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.fname %>
<% end -%>

Comment: ID of the parent here is 1.

Comment: Fairly long output, so here's a screenshot:

http://cl.ly/image/3v0O1m3p2A1a/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-13%20at%209.45.09%20PM.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68787/discussion-between-littlerobothead-and-anthony).